# manejo de fechas en java

Tags: java, apache-netbeans

Crear una clase Fecha, que tenga como atributos seis enteros: anio, mes, dia, horas, minutos
y segundos, igualmente un booleano formato que indica si la hora se muestra en formato
de 12 o 24 horas. ( 12/02/2021- 05:16:24 PM à 12/02/2021- 17:16:24 )
En el main class, crear dos Fechas, una inicializada de forma aleatoria y la otra con la misma
fecha que la primera.
Luego mostrar las fechas en formato de 24H o 12H según lo indique el atributo formato,
posteriormente modificar el atributo formato y volver a mostrar la fecha, para mostrar una
fecha se debe emplear siempre el método toString().
Colocar la primera fecha en 12/02/2021-18:02:59 y la segunda marcando 21/01/2022-
05:19:23 AM y mostrar la diferencia, en días, horas, minutos y segundos; que hay entre
ambas fechas.
Crear un método que reciba cierta cantidad de días, horas, minutos y segundos y se la sume
a la fecha actual. (ejemplo: si el reloj marca las 12/01/2021-05:10:20 AM y le pasan 20 días,
20 horas, 20 minutos y 50 segundos, debe quedar marcando 02/02/2021-01:31:10 AM

Comment: Las preguntas que solo exponen enunciados de ejercicios sin mayor contexto de lo avanzado al momento así como dudas puntuales no se ajustan a [ask] y terminan cerradas. Lea por favor el [tour]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: La mejor forma de explicarnos es con el código que has intentado hacer, los errores y problemas. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).